# Check if a pear key is present in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, key-value

Apologies for the newbie question but I'm relatively new to PHP and want to do something fairly simple... If I have an array of keys & values (pears):

```
$arrayOfPears = array(
                      "Green Anjou" => [ 7,
                                         "plump",
                                         "ripe",
                                         "juicy",
                                         "green"
                                        ],
                      "Bartlett"     => [ 2,
                                          "moderately plump",
                                          "unripe",
                                          "sweet",
                                          "greeny-yellow"
                                         ],
                      "Comice"       =>  [ 3,
                                           "rather plump",
                                           "ripe",
                                           "blinding",
                                           "deep-green"
                                         ],
                      "Plum"          => [ 6,
                                           "rotund",
                                           "over-ripe",
                                           "sweet",
                                           "purple",
                                           "not really a pear, as far as I'm aware"
                                          ]
                      );
```

I am able to access a specific pear's value and use it for a comparison operation. For example:

```
if($arrayofPears['Comice'][2] == "ripe") {
   $nibble = true;
   return $nibble;
}
```

Does return a true `$nibble`. However, what I would like to be able to do is check first if the `Comise` key is present in the array, *before* I try to enter the if statement and find out if I get a true `$nibble`.

So... how do I check if any 'Comice' are present in this situation, before committing myself to enter the conditional?

Comment: Is that pair or pear? If that is pair, edit your question.

Comment: What if, as a total curve-ball, I actually meant to write apples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
if(array_key_exists("Comice",$arrayOfPear){
//Do the Loop
}
else{
//Don't enter the loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. I will try this out and see.

Comment: You are welcome!  Please mark it as the right answer if it works